# Averaging dataframes with many string columns and display back all the columns

Tags: pandas, numpy, python-3.7

I have struggled with this even after looking at the various past answers to no avail.
My data consists of columns numeric and non numeric. I'd like to average the numeric columns and display my data on the GUI together with the information on the non-numeric columns.The non numeric columns have info such as names,rollno,stream while the numeric columns contain students marks for various subjects. It works well when dealing with one dataframe but fails when I combine two or more dataframes in which it returms only the average of the numeric columns and displays it leaving the non numeric columns undisplayed. Below is one of the codes I've tried so far.

```
df=pd.concat((df3,df5))
dfs =df.groupby(df.index,level=0).mean()
headers = list(dfs)
self.marks_table.setRowCount(dfs.shape[0])
self.marks_table.setColumnCount(dfs.shape[1])
self.marks_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers)
df_array = dfs.values
for row in range(dfs.shape[0]):
    for col in range(dfs.shape[1]):
        self.marks_table.setItem(row, col,QTableWidgetItem(str(df_array[row,col])))
```

A working code should return averages in something like this

```
   STREAM ADM  NAME        KCPE  ENG  KIS
0  EAGLE  663  FLOYCE ATI  250   43    5
1  EAGLE  664  VERONICA    252   32   33
2  EAGLE  665  MACREEN A   341   23   23
3  EAGLE  666  BRIDGIT     286   23    2
```

Rather than

```
     ADM   KCPE   ENG   KIS
0  663.0  250.0  27.5  18.5
1  664.0  252.0  26.5  33.0
2  665.0  341.0  17.5  22.5
3  666.0  286.0  38.5  23.5
```

Sample data

```
Df1 = pd.DataFrame({
     'STREAM':[NORTH,SOUTH],
     'ADM':[437,238,439], 
'NAME':[JAMES,MARK,PETER], 
'KCPE':[233,168,349], 
'ENG':[70,28,79],
'KIS':[37,82,79],
'MAT':[67,38,29]})
Df2 = pd.DataFrame({
     'STREAM':[NORTH,SOUTH],
     'ADM':[437,238,439], 
'NAME':[JAMES,MARK,PETER], 
'KCPE':[233,168,349], 
'ENG':[40,12,56],
'KIS':[33,43,43],
'MAT':[22,58,23]})
```

Comment: Can you please give some raw data?

Comment: How do I upload? Do I copy and paste here?

Comment: @Ptar Please avoid using the pyqt5 tag unnecessarily. Your application may be using that library but your problem has nothing to do with pyqt5.

Comment: Check the sample data given in the edit

Comment: NameError: name 'NORTH' is not defined

Comment: Omission of quotation somewhere, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question not clear. However guessing the origin of question based on content. I have modified your datframes which were not well done by adding a stream called '`CENTRAL`', see

```
Df1 = pd.DataFrame({'STREAM':['NORTH','SOUTH', 'CENTRAL'],'ADM':[437,238,439], 'NAME':['JAMES','MARK','PETER'],'KCPE':[233,168,349],'ENG':[70,28,79],'KIS':[37,82,79],'MAT':[67,38,29]})

Df2 = pd.DataFrame({     'STREAM':['NORTH','SOUTH','CENTRAL'],'ADM':[437,238,439], 'NAME':['JAMES','MARK','PETER'],'KCPE':[233,168,349],'ENG':[40,12,56],'KIS':[33,43,43],'MAT':[22,58,23]})
```

I have assumed you want to merge the two dataframes and find avarage

```
df3=Df2.append(Df1)


df3.groupby(['STREAM','ADM','NAME'],as_index=False).sum()
```

Outcome

[image]